# Why are cruise ships on a 14 day schedule?

Tags: cruising

So it seems that a lot of cruise ship itineraries are on a 14 day schedule - 9/5 or 5/5/4, with an occasional 21 day schedule - 8/8/5 or 12/9.  Is there a particular reason for this other than operator convenience?

Comment: Because it allows cruises to start on the same day of the week?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it not really about travel.

Answer (score 4):

Actually the [average length of a cruise ship journey is 7.2 days](http://www.statisticbrain.com/cruise-ship-industry-statistics/), so you may find that's just confirmation bias that you're seeing.

Regardless, like any other business model, it's likely that it's based on supply and demand, that those lengths are the most popular with customers who want two weeks off work or have to fly to the start/end and want a gap in between.  So from surveys, responses, sales and feedback, those will just be the lengths that they've settled on.

Comment: I'm not sure how an average length of voyage being 7 days addresses the question being asked at all; what's being observed is that the itineraries follow a *cycle* of multiple voyages adding up to 14 days before rotating through the cycle again. (Personally, if I had to guess, it's because crew rotations, maintenance, etc, are probably scheduled around those two week intervals, but that'd be total conjecture.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz well he's saying that a lot of them are on this long schedule, and research seems to indicate that most of them aren't....

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz OH I see! The sum adding up, rather than the actual cruise length.  Hmm, probably the same reasons combining my answer and your comments...but as you say, it then comes down to conjecture...